# How to use FAB's OnVisibilityChangedListener

Tags: android, floating-action-button

There is an  `OnVisibilityChangedListener`  class in FAB source with `onShown` and `onHidden` methods. I wanted to use it on a FAB like you use  `OnClickListener` on a view but it didn't work.

Please, do you have an idea how I could do this?

**EDIT**

---

After Applying Shadab K's answer

```
public class GagActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    FloatingActionButton shareButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate called");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gag);

        //FAB Buttons
        shareButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.share_fab_main);
    }

    final FloatingActionButton.OnVisibilityChangedListener addVisibilityChanged = new FloatingActionButton.OnVisibilityChangedListener() {
        public void onShown(final FloatingActionButton fab) {
            super.onShown(fab);
            Log.d(TAG, "Visibility changed");
        }
        public void onHidden(final FloatingActionButton fab) {
            super.onHidden(fab);
            Log.d(TAG, "Visibility hideen");
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Update the post with your code as well.

Comment: @ShadabK I have done that.

Comment: `shareButton.hide(OnVisibilityChangedListener listener)` and `shareButton.show(OnVisibilityChangedListener listener)` will take it as a parameter.Call that using `shareButton.show(addVisibilityChanged)` or `shareButton.hide(addVisibilityChanged)`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that `FloatingActionButton.OnVisibilityChangedListener` can only be used when you call `fab.show(yourListener)` or `fab.hide(yourListener)` explicitly, which does not really make sense when you want to react to these events.

I solved my problem by using animation listeners like so:

```
fab.addOnHideAnimationListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {
                // react to the fab being hidden
            }
        });

fab.addOnShowAnimationListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {
                // react to the fab being shown
            }
        });
```

This seems to be way from perfect, but was the simplest solution I could find so far.

Answer (score -1):

You can use it in this fashion show below:

```
final OnVisibilityChangedListener addVisibilityChangedListener = new OnVisibilityChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onShown(final FloatingActionButton fab) {
        super.onShown(fab);
    }

    @Override
    public void onHidden(final FloatingActionButton fab) {
        super.onHidden(fab);
        floatingActionButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_add_white_24dp);
        floatingActionButton.show();
    }
};
```

Comment: It seems not to be working.  `addVisibilityChangedListener` is saying field never used.